# Updating A Column if a Value Is Changed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a column representing line numbers. The line numbes correspond to lines in a text area.

Say if I have 10 lines and I go to line 5 and make a new `insert`, I will now have 11 lines. This means that all the line number values after the `insert` statement (I have my `insert` statement working fine) need to be updated by one. Is there a way PHP can update these multiple line number values? I've tried using the `LAST_INSERTID()` function and adding 1 but with no success.

My attempts:

```
INSERT INTO Table(LineNumber, Text) VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1', '' )";
```

Which didn't really make sense

```
if($linenumber <= mysqli_insert_id() { 
    $update = "UPDATE Table SET LineNumber='$linenumber' ";
}
```

I also tried a `for` loop in the javascript which calls the function to try to carry out an `UPDATE` statement for each value of Line Number

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I also tried a for loop in the javascript which calls the function to try to carry out an UPDATE statement for each value of Line Number

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database and do a mass update:

```
UPDATE TABLE *tablename* SET line_number = line_number + 1 WHERE line_number >= 5
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO *tablename* (line_number, ...othervals) VALUES (5, ...othervals)
```

Comment: I would however strongly consider if there is not a better solution. Massive text files will  take a long time to update this way. If you for example  have a text file of a thousand lines and need to insert one at the top, the database will have to update 1000 records.